# How do I remove an element from a list, edit it, then append the edit back into the list?

Tags: python, list, csv

I am creating a webscraper but some of the numbers use '/' in them. I have finally been able to put the stats from my list into a csv file the way I'd like but I am running into an issue where a stat reads back as '0 / 0 / 0' where the zeroes are wins/draws/losses.
How do I edit the list to remove the '/' characters and replace with ',''s but not add quotations to my csv file?

```
for largestrong_tag in stat_grayhound:
    array.append(largestrong_tag.text)
```

Gives me my list, and my writer puts it into the csv file without quotes like I want.

```
['Grayhound', '553', '401 / 0 / 152', '51252', '44023', '14017', '1.16']
```

So to remove the '/' from the list, and re add the values I tried.

```
for i, num in enumerate(array):
    array[i] = num.replace('/',',')
#AND
for i, num in enumerate(array):
    array[i] = num.replace('/',' ')
```

But this code adds unnecessary spaces and quotes in my CSV file.

```
CSVFile>>> Grayhound,553,"401 , 0 , 152",51252,44023,14017,1.16
#AND
CSVFile>>> Grayhound,553,401   0   152,51252,44023,14017,1.16
```

I would like for the 2nd element of my list to be edited to read more like.

```
CSVFile: Grayhound,553,401,0,152,51252,44023,14017,1.16
```

Full code @ 
https://www.codepile.net/pile/lVG3DlVx

Comment: This then adds quotes to the CSV file. "401,0,152" So I've tried using QUOTE_NONE but that forces escape chars.

Comment: Do you want to have 3 list entries - one for wins, draws, losses - or a single one?

Comment: I'd prefer to have 1 for each, and I've been scouring how to edit the python text accordingly by trying to index out the element then edit the element. So 3 separate entries would be awesome!

Comment: Reading the answers and your comments below, please post your full code including how you generate the csv. Your issue is probably with the csv writer, since double quotes are not introduced by any of the commands mentioned here.

Comment: It didn't *add* unnecessary space; it left the unnecessary space that was already there alone. The quotes are added because you are using the field delimiter `,` in the value of a field.

Comment: Sorry! First time using the website for my own question. Usually most things have already been asked. Thank you again!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should split the data before you add it to your list:

```
for largestrong_tag in stat_grayhound:
    array.extend(largestrong_tag.text.split(' / '))
```

This will split any results with " / " delimiters, and create separate entries for them as you want, and the CSV will adjust accordingly.

This turns your array from your example to:

> ['Grayhound', '553', '401', '0', '152', '51252', '44023', '14017', '1.16']

And consequently your CSV would reflect the above state to the desired result.

Since you spoke of some issues, I'm guessing they were typos, because it worked out fine for me, here's a [repl link](https://repl.it/repls/AttractiveImmaterialPatterns) to the full code.

Comment: This adds quotes to the CSV file. "401,0,152"

Comment: I copy and pasted and commented out my ```array.append``` to test the ```array.extend``` still added quotes.,

Comment: Please add the full code including how you generate the csv to the question. This does not seem to be an issue with generating the array but with writing it to a file.

Comment: This did it!!! I must have forgot something and i re read the comment and tried again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing `'/'` replace `' / '`. The fact is that it didn't add extra space. It just left spaces that were already here. And this should work:

```py
myData = ['Grayhound', '553', '401 / 0 / 152', '51252', '44023', '14017', '1.16']
myNewData = []

for idx, val in enumerate(myData):
    currentData = val.replace(' / ',',').split(",")
    for i in currentData:
        myNewData.append(i)

print(myNewData)
```

Comment: This still adds quotes to the CSV file. ```num.replace(' / ',' ') and num.replace(' / ',',')```